# Reference Request: Ratio of Computational Complexity to Predictive Quality

Tags: references, time-complexity, computational-statistics

I remember coming across a "performance metric" which was the ratio between the MSE and the computational time.  However, I can't seem to recall the name of this metric or a reference.

Does anyone know what this is called or have a reference to a similar metric?